# Search and replace JSON in Mysql with regex

Tags: mysql, json, regex, search, replace

Is it possible to search and replace with a regex expression in MySQL?

I have a thousand values on a column containing a JSON string, somewhere inside each JSON are several occurrences of a string that I have to change.

I've already made a PHP script that do the job, but it is a little slow.

Is there a nicer way to do that using only MySQL?

Something like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET value = "disabled" WHERE data REGEXP '{"field": "(.+)"}'
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, which might provide the tool you need.